# Count mutiple occurences of a word on the same line using grep

Tags: shell, unix, grep

Here I made a small script that take input from user searching some pattern from a file and displays required no of lines from that file where the pattern is found. Although this code is searching the pattern line wise due to standard grep practice. I mean if the pattern occurs twice on the same line,  i want the output to print twice. Hope I make some sense.

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /dev/null>copy.txt
echo "Please enter the sentence you want to search:"
read "inputVar"
echo "Please enter the name of the file in which you want to search:"
read "inputFileName"
echo "Please enter the number of lines you want to copy:"
read "inputLineNumber"
[[-z "$inputLineNumber"]] || inputLineNumber=20
cat /dev/null > copy.txt
for N in `grep -n $inputVar $inputFileName | cut -d ":" -f1`
do
  LIMIT=`expr $N + $inputLineNumber`
  sed -n $N,${LIMIT}p $inputFileName >> copy.txt
  echo "-----------------------" >> copy.txt
done
cat copy.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, the task is to count number of pattern occurrences in line. It can be done like so:

```
count=$((`echo "$line" | sed -e "s|$pattern|\n|g" | wc -l` - 1))
```

Suppose you have one file to read. Then, code will be following:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
pattern="an."

#reading file line by line
cat -n $file | while read input
do
    #storing line to $tmp
    tmp=`echo $input | grep "$pattern"`
    #counting occurrences count
    count=$((`echo "$tmp" | sed -e "s|$pattern|\n|g" | wc -l` - 1))
    #printing $tmp line $count times
    for i in `seq 1 $count`
    do
        echo $tmp
    done
done
```

I checked this for pattern "an." and input:

```
I pass here an example of many 'an' letters
an
ananas
an-an-as
```

Output is:

```
$ ./test.sh input 
1 I pass here an example of many 'an' letters
1 I pass here an example of many 'an' letters
1 I pass here an example of many 'an' letters
3 ananas
4 an-an-as
4 an-an-as
```

Adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Using `grep -o` instead of sed would be quicker to write (same intend though).

Answer (score 0):

How about using awk?

Assume the pattern you are searching for is in variable $pattern and the file you are checking is $file
The

```
count=`awk 'BEGIN{n=0}{n+=split($0,a,"'$pattern'")-1}END {print n}' $file`
```

or for a line

```
count=`echo $line | awk '{n=split($0,a,"'$pattern'")-1;print n}`
```